# insert query issue i get"#1054 - Unknown column 'Dorel' in 'field list'", please some advice you can see my query bellow

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS`MyDatabase1`;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produse` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nume` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `denumire` varchar(44) NOT NULL,
  `pret` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `descriere` varchar(150)NOT NULL,
  `categorie` varchar(15)NOT NULL,
  `data`varchar(15),
  `poza`varchar(300),
  `telefon`int(20)NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);



INSERT INTO produse (`id`,`nume`,`denumire`,`pret`,`descriere`,`categorie`,`data`,`poza`,`telefon`) VALUES
( `Dorel`,`auto`, `1500`,`de vanzare bmw g30 pret in euro`,`auto-moto`,`2017 may 18`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/G30.jpg`,`0789 666666`),
( `Gicu` ,`motocicleta`,`3700`,`vand moto bmw 9r ireprosabil`,`auto-moto`,`2018.08.23`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/9r.jpg`,`0788 884221`),
( `Robi`, `manusa box`, `500`,`de vanzare nou`,`sport`,`1976 Apr 12 15:42:27`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/box.jpg`,`0788 321654`),
( `Spiderman`,`canoe`,`1000`,`vand pret in Dinar`,`sport`,`2018 Feb 30`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/canoe.jpg`,`0744 434 534`),
( `Wonder Woman`,`cuptor`,`40000`,`vand cuptor secon hand bun`,`home`,`2045 Ian 23`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/cuptor.jpeg`,`0788 889 889`),
(`Batman`,`e30`,`3700`,`vand bmw e30 stare exceptionala`,`auto-moto`,`2016 04 20`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/e30.jpg`,`0999876`),
(`Elvis Presley`,`motocicleta Harley`,`12000`,`schimb cu viata de preferat lunga`,`auto-moto`,`1977 May 23`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/Harley.jpg`,`1111` ),
(`Michael Jackson`,`arc compound`,`5000`,`vand hoyt nu am ce sa spun despre`,`sport`,`1999 03 12`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/hoyt.jpg`,`0333 333 333`),
(`Traian basescu`,`Lada`,`24000`,`vand sau schimb cu vapor`,`auto-moto`,`2000.01.01`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/lada.jpg`,`0000 000 000`),
(`Victor Ponta`,`laptop Dell`,`3000`,`schimb cu permis de pescuit`,`auto-moto`,`2013.06.06`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/laptop.jpg`,`0999 787878`),
(`Vin Diesel`,`Indian`,`10000`,`mint condition Indian for sell`,`auto-moto`,`2014.09.09`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/indian.jpg`,`0100 5555 22`),
(`Elena Udrea`,`mobila`,`000`,`schimb cu lenjerie intima`,`home`,`2013.08.07`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/mobila.jpg`,`0888 888 888`),
(`Ronaldo`,`nevasta`,`000`,`schimb nevasta cu o motocicleta`,`home`,`2018.06.23`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/nevasta.jpg`,`78878878`),
(`Marko Bela`,`Lada Niva`,`45000`,`cumpar Lada Niva, cu pret mai ieftin nu discut `,`auto-moto`,
 `2018.05.12`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/niva.jpg`,`898989`),
(`Gizi`,`parapanta ozone`,`1500`,`vand parapanta second,folosit putin`,`sport`,`2018.05.23`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/ozone.jpg`,`0745 233 445`),
(`Simona Halep`,`Racheta alba`,`0000`,`dau gratis`,`sport`,`2018.04.31`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/racheta.jpg`,`090909`),
(`Valentino Rossi`,`s100rr`,`500`,`For as little as 500 you can get brand new bmws 1000rr`,`automoto`,`2018.01.01`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/s100rr.jpg`,`7878787`),
(`Superman`,`samsung tv`,`23000`,`vand tv-ul ieftin,numai acum numai azi`,`electronice`,`2018.02.12`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/tv.jpg`,`666666`),
(`Kojak`,`uscator de par`,`200`,`vand uscator de par ca nu mai am par`,`electronice`,`2018.06.08`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/uscator.jpg`,`5666666`),
(`Garcea`,`vw polo`,`20`,`vand volkswagen polo merita vazut`,`auto-moto`,`2018.05.23`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/Polo.jpg`,`45454533`),
(`Dorin Florea`,`pavaje`,`100`,`de vanzare metrucub pretavantajos`,`home`,`2018.03.03`,`D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/pavaj.jpg`,`0265 265 310`);
```

Comment: You need to quote strings inside SQL. e.g. ...VALUES ('dorel',..      You should shorten your question and move the error message in the body. Furthermore this question is very specific to your problem and not broad enough

Comment: @Loui: Check out the answer, I have corrected your INSERT statement CODE

Comment: Obviously, you can illustrate this problem with a much simpler example.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error message because you used the back quote in VALUES list also, which is only used for columns, I have corrected your INSERT statement try it now.

```
INSERT INTO produse (nume,denumire,pret,descriere,categorie,data,poza,telefon) VALUES
( 'Dorel','auto', '1500','de vanzare bmw g30 pret in euro','auto-moto','2017 may 18','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/G30.jpg','0789 666666'),
( 'Gicu' ,'motocicleta','3700','vand moto bmw 9r ireprosabil','auto-moto','2018.08.23','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/9r.jpg','0788 884221'),
( 'Robi', 'manusa box', '500','de vanzare nou','sport','1976 Apr 12 15:42:27','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/box.jpg','0788 321654'),
( 'Spiderman','canoe','1000','vand pret in Dinar','sport','2018 Feb 30','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/canoe.jpg','0744 434 534'),
( 'Wonder Woman','cuptor','40000','vand cuptor secon hand bun','home','2045 Ian 23','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/cuptor.jpeg','0788 889 889'),
('Batman','e30','3700','vand bmw e30 stare exceptionala','auto-moto','2016 04 20','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/e30.jpg','0999876'),
('Elvis Presley','motocicleta Harley','12000','schimb cu viata de preferat lunga','auto-moto','1977 May 23','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/Harley.jpg','1111' ),
('Michael Jackson','arc compound','5000','vand hoyt nu am ce sa spun despre','sport','1999 03 12','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/hoyt.jpg','0333 333 333'),
('Traian basescu','Lada','24000','vand sau schimb cu vapor','auto-moto','2000.01.01','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/lada.jpg','0000 000 000'),
('Victor Ponta','laptop Dell','3000','schimb cu permis de pescuit','auto-moto','2013.06.06','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/laptop.jpg','0999 787878'),
('Vin Diesel','Indian','10000','mint condition Indian for sell','auto-moto','2014.09.09','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/indian.jpg','0100 5555 22'),
('Elena Udrea','mobila','000','schimb cu lenjerie intima','home','2013.08.07','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/mobila.jpg','0888 888 888'),
('Ronaldo','nevasta','000','schimb nevasta cu o motocicleta','home','2018.06.23','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/nevasta.jpg','78878878'),
('Marko Bela','Lada Niva','45000','cumpar Lada Niva, cu pret mai ieftin nu discut ','auto-moto',
 '2018.05.12','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/niva.jpg','898989'),
('Gizi','parapanta ozone','1500','vand parapanta second,folosit putin','sport','2018.05.23','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/ozone.jpg','0745 233 445'),
('Simona Halep','Racheta alba','0000','dau gratis','sport','2018.04.31','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/racheta.jpg','090909'),
('Valentino Rossi','s100rr','500','For as little as 500 you can get brand new bmws 1000rr','automoto','2018.01.01','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/s100rr.jpg','7878787'),
('Superman','samsung tv','23000','vand tv-ul ieftin,numai acum numai azi','electronice','2018.02.12','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/tv.jpg','666666'),
('Kojak','uscator de par','200','vand uscator de par ca nu mai am par','electronice','2018.06.08','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/uscator.jpg','5666666'),
('Garcea','vw polo','20','vand volkswagen polo merita vazut','auto-moto','2018.05.23','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/Polo.jpg','45454533'),
('Dorin Florea','pavaje','100','de vanzare metrucub pretavantajos','home','2018.03.03','D:/Xamp/htdocs/poze/pavaj.jpg','0265 265 310');
```

Comment: If information is useful to you then you can accept the answer.